# How to restrict alert to dismiss after button click?

Tags: ios, swift, button, alert

**How to restrict alert to dismiss after button click?**

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

// Create the actions
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
    UIAlertAction in
    NSLog("OK Pressed")
}
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
    UIAlertAction in
    NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
}

// Add the actions
alertController.addAction(okAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

// Present the controller
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is there anyway to restrict dismiss of the alert even if I click okAction button?

Comment: Why? What's your use? You can show a new alert on okButton action.

Comment: If you do not dismiss, how will you leave the alert ? You can do this by calling again the alert, in the handler of the OK button, by adding this at the end:           DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
          self.testAlert(sender) }
where testAlert is the IBAction that triggers initially the alert. But once again, you may end up in an infinite alert loop.         
        
        So, you need a cancel button in alert to close it.
     let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Annuler", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert?.addAction(cancelAction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I tested this in line with my comment:

```
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
    UIAlertAction in
      NSLog("OK Pressed")
      DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
        self.testAlert(sender)  // Or whatever functionalists that created the alertController
    }
}
```